# Can i specify the FAST keypoints number i get when using opencv FastFeatureDetector

Tags: opencv, keypoint

i am using openCV FastFeatureDetector to extract fast keypoints from image.
but the number of the FastFeatureDetector detect  is not a const number.
i want set the  max keypoints number FastFeatureDetector get.
Can i specify the FAST key points number i get when using openCV FastFeatureDetector
How?

Comment: The number of keypoints depends on the image. You cannot force the detector to find keypoints where there aren't any. So the only way to get a constant number is to specify the maximum number of output points and then guarantee that every image will have more than that.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem and after a brief search I found DynamicAdaptedFeatureDetector that iteratively detects keypoints until the desired number is found.

check: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#dynamicadaptedfeaturedetector

code:

```
int maxKeypoints, minKeypoints;

Ptr<FastAdjuster> adjust = new FastAdjuster();
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = new DynamicAdaptedFeatureDetector(adjust,minKeypoints,maxKeypoints,100);

vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector->detect(image, keypoints);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am offering main part of the code, in that case you can set the number of key-points as what you expected. Good luck.

```
# define MAX_FEATURE 500  // specify maximum expected feature size

string detectorType = "FAST"; 
string descriptorType = "SIFT";

detector = FeatureDetector::create(detectorType);
extractor = DescriptorExtractor::create(descriptorType);

Mat descriptors;
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

detector->detect(img, keypoints);
if( keypoints.size() > MAX_FEATURE )
{
    cout << " [INFO] key-point 1 size: " << keypoints.size() << endl;
    KeyPointsFilter::retainBest(keypoints, MAX_FEATURE);
}
cout << " [INFO] key-point 2 size: " << keypoints.size() << endl;
extractor->compute(img, keypoints, descriptors);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solution is to detect as many keypoints as possible with a low threshold and apply adaptive non-maximal suppression (ANMS) described in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323388062_Efficient_adaptive_non-maximal_suppression_algorithms_for_homogeneous_spatial_keypoint_distribution). You can specify the number of points you need. Additionally, for free, you get your points homogenously distributed on the image. Codes can be found [here](https://github.com/BAILOOL/ANMS-Codes).